# C# 2D array of doubles and strings

Tags: c#, ado.net, excel-2010

I am trying to get quite a large SQL query into an array in C#. However, the values from the query are made up of doubles and strings. How do I account for that? Because, using the below method (just putting everything in as a string) does not work in my worksheet, as the numbers are formatted as text.

```
String sql = "SELECT Ticker, Cusip, Shares, value, Price, " +....

string[,] data = new string[5000, 10]; //multi-dimentional array

string connectionString = Database.ConnectionString();
using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
{
    connection.Open();
    using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(sql, connection))
    {

        SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            String ticker = (string)reader["ActTicker"];
            String cusip = (string)reader["Cusip9"];
            double shares = (double)reader["shares"];
            double price = (double)reader["price"];
            double value = (double)reader["value"];

            data[row, 0] = ticker;
            data[row, 1] = "=iferror(bdp(\"" + cusip + " cusip\", \"GICS_SECTOR_NAME\"),0)";
            data[row, 2] = "=iferror(bdp(\"" + cusip + " cusip\", \"SECURITY_TYP\"),0)";
            data[row, 3] = "=iferror(bdp(\"" + cusip + " cusip\", \"CUR_MKT_CAP\"),0)";
            data[row, 4] = "=iferror(bdp(\"" + cusip + " cusip\", \"VOLUME_AVG_10D\"),0)";
            data[row, 5] = shares.ToString();
            data[row, 6] = value.ToString();
            data[row, 7] = price.ToString();
            data[row, 8] = "=iferror(bdp(\"" + cusip + " cusip\", \"last price\"),0)";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why can't you use a `Dictionary<Double, String>` for this?

Comment: Is there any reason to use an array.  This is what DataTables are for.  They can be automattically loaded from a SQL Query.

Comment: You should learn how to use Classes and List. You'll have a problem if there's more than 5000 entry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a DataTable, or if you want something a bit more lightweight and strongly typed then create your own custom data structure.

```
public struct MyCustomData 
{
    String ticker;
    String cusip;
    double shares;
    double price;
    double value;
}
```

The make an array out of *that*

```
MyCustomData[] data = new MyCustomData[5000];
.
.
.
data[row].ticker = ticker;
data[row].cusip = "=iferror(bdp(\"" + cusip + " cusip\", \"GICS_SECTOR_NAME\"),0)";
.
.
.
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    public SqlConnection myConnection = new SqlConnection("");

    public DataTable Select(string sTSQL)
    {
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        try
        {
            myConnection.Open();
            SqlDataReader myReader = null;
            SqlCommand myCommand = new SqlCommand(sTSQL,  myConnection);
            myReader = myCommand.ExecuteReader();

            dt.Load(myReader);

        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
            dt = null;
        }
        finally
        {
            try
            {
                myConnection.Close();
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
            }
        }

        return dt;
    }
```